# Approximation or closed form formula for a multiplicative series

Tags: sequences-and-series

In the below T is of the order of $946442288$ , $n$ can range from $1$ to about $800000$ , 
$m$ is of the order of $92646759$.

Is there an approximation to the below that will let me calculate the below product quickly?

$$\left(1-\frac nT\right) \cdot\left(1-\frac n{T-1}\right) \cdot \left(1-\frac n{T-2}\right)\cdot \cdots\cdot \left(1-\frac n{T-m}\right)$$

Comment: If my calculations are correct , the series has a closed form given by : $$ \frac{\frac{(T-n)!}{(T-n-m-1)!}}{\frac{(T)!}{(T-m-1)!}} $$

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit I confirm your calculation.  Now Stirling's formula should give a good approximation.

Comment: @saulspatz Your $(1-m/T)^n$ looks like a reasonable approximation

Comment: @Henry Perhaps, but I don't like the derivation, now that I've seen a closed-form expression for the product.

Comment: Why were all the answers deleted ? They seem fine to me

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit because yours is better

Comment: If i now need to calculate the sum of terms consisting of this product for m going from 0 to to a number M  would there be a closed form formula or failing that an approximate formula  I am interested in this sum because it is the equivalent of the birthday bound distincts calculation where the sample is drawn from a restricted T values with a pool of n distincts and for m trials.  For this i need to sum this product for m going from 0 to the number of trials M.